# Custom format for a number on a horizontal axis of a chart based on the axis's tick value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to conditionally format the label of the horizontal axis in an chart based on the value.

Here is how I get to what it is am trying to format:

- Right click the Horizontal Axis Labels and select "Horizontal Axis
  Properties"

[image]

- Select the "Number" list view item in the left side list view and
  then select "Custom" in the Category list box.

[image]

I am simply trying to display K&1 when the value is equal to 1.

--> K&1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

I Currently have the expression set to **="Grade #0"**, however, when I attempt to use a conditional custom format such as **="[=1][Grade K&#0];[>1][Grade #0]"** the format is ignored. Any ideas on a how I can apply the formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following...

```
[=1]"Grade K"&#0;[>1]"Grade "#0
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how to apply that value to as a string literal. When I use the expression: =IIF(Fields!CALC_IsGradeLevelMenu.Value,"[=1]Grade K&#0;[>1]Grade #0","Level #0"), I get - [=1]Grade 1 [=1] Grade2 [=1] Grade 3....

Comment: The text that I supplied...

[=1]"Grade K&"#0;[>1]"Grade "#0

is what you need to enter in Horizontal Axis Properties > Number > Custom Format field. The first part ([=1]"Grade K&"#0) says that if value = 1 then display string "Grade K&" followed by number. The second part ([>1]"Grade "#0) says that if value > 1 then display string "Grade " followed by number. The resulting labels will be...

Grade K&1, Grade 2, Grade 3, Grade 4, ...

If you want to leave out the word "Grade" then use the format...

[=1]"K&"#0;[>1]#0

which will produce the following labels...

K&1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have to enter the expression as a string. The value is being interpreted as a string. I will see what I can come up with. =[=1] will cause an invalid expression whereas ="[=1]" is fine.